# Word 2010 VBA: Search for text and replace with section break

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am searching for specific text within a document, deleting the text and then adding a section break. I can only get this code to work for one instance.  When I tried a do while loop, checking each line, Word crashed.

```
With Selection.Find
        .Text = "INSTRUCTOROVERVIEW"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute
With Selection
    If .Find.Forward = True Then
        .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
    Else
        .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    End If
    .Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne
    If .Find.Forward = True Then
        .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    Else
        .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
    End If
    .Find.Execute
End With
Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakNextPage
```

Answer (score 1):

You should show your loop-code as well.

However, setting

```
.Wrap = wdFindStop
```

will prevent the the Find from running the code indefinitely, which is probably why it is crashing. Using `wdFindContinue` will cause the search to continue from the beginning of the document, over and over.

However, you should also check the result returned by `Find.Execute`. It is a `Boolean` value (True or False) indicating whether the Find was successful. If is not successful you should use `Exit Do` or `Exit For` to break out of your loop.